# Not able to implement Youtube API in my website

Tags: php

I am trying to implement youtube API to upload videos from my website.I Know how to implement.But thing is i am not getting developer key using this url 'http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/'.I tried so many times BUt it is showing 404 error(not fount). Anybody is there to help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are trying the wrong url, try this one:

https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt